# How to return error code from a python script to Execute Process Task in SSIS?

Tags: python, batch-file, ssis

I've a python script which I call from SSIS using Execute Process Task. How can I return error code from the python script and force the process task to fail/succeed based on the error codes from the python script.

Comment: `sys.exit(0)` for success, `sys.exit(1)` for failure.

Comment: Awesome. That works. Thank you.